# I am trying to rotate a triangle

Tags: graphics, rotation

I have a circle, and then a triangle in the middle of the circle. I want to rotate the triangle around the center of the triangle. Kind of like rotating it 360 degrees. This is my code so far

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawArc(120, 120, 100, 100, 0, 360);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    int[] x = {160, 170, 180};
    int[] y = {150, 190, 150};
    g.drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpinningCircle");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new SpinningCircle());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

`
Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you have a question? What is it you need help with? What have you tried that hasn't worked and how did it fail?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions